# Java Generics enforcing compatible wildcards

Tags: java, generics

I've these classes.

```
class RedSocket {}
class GreenSocket {}
class RedWire {}
class GreenWire {}
```

I've a class which uses 2 generic types

```
public class Connection<W, S> {}
```

where W is Wire type & S is Socket type.

I'm trying to enforce compile time check to ensure that socket & wire have the same color.

I tried doing this:

```
public class Connection<W extends Wire & Color, S extends Socket & Color> {}

interface Color {}

interface Red extends Color {}
interface Green extends Color {}

interface Socket {}
interface Wire {}

class RedSocket implements Socket, Red {}
class GreenSocket implements Socket, Green {}
class RedWire implements Wire,  Red {}
class GreenWire implements Wire, Green {}
```

But this doesn't really ensure that the `Color` used is same for both generic types and still lets me do this:

```
public class Connection<W extends Wire & Color, S extends Socket & Color> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Connection<RedWire, GreenSocket>();
        new Connection<GreenWire, RedSocket>();
    }
}
```

(Why this happens has been explained brilliantly by Radiodef [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217236/can-the-generic-type-of-a-generic-java-method-be-used-to-enforce-the-type-of-arg))

How can I enforce compile time check to ensure that socket & wire have the same color?

Comment: Probably no one care, but is there any reason why you've chosen `M` and `Q` as type for Wire & Socket ?

Comment: Ah! My original program had different entities. I changed everything else but forgot to change these. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll change it. :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Seems that it's better to parameterize `Socket` and `Wire` with color:

```
interface Socket<C extends Color> {}
interface Wire<C extends Color> {}

class RedSocket implements Socket<Red> {}
class GreenSocket implements Socket<Green> {}
class RedWire implements Wire<Red> {}
class GreenWire implements Wire<Green> {}
```

This way you can introduce one more generic parameter to the `Connection`:

```
public class Connection<C extends Color, M extends Wire<C>, Q extends Socket<C>> {...}
```

And use it like this:

```
new Connection<Red, RedWire, RedSocket>(); // ok
new Connection<Green, GreenWire, GreenSocket>(); // ok
new Connection<Green, GreenWire, RedSocket>(); // error
```

Answer (score 36):

As a minor variation of [Tagir Valeev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32244114/3182664): You can possibly get rid of the third generic parameter of the `Connection` class, by making its constructor `private` (or maybe package visible), and offer a factory method for creating `Connection` instances that ensures that the `Color` type is the same for the given `Wire`- and `Socket` types:

```
class Connection<
    W extends Wire<? extends Color>, 
    S extends Socket<? extends Color>> 
{
    static <C extends Color, 
        W extends Wire<C>, 
        S extends Socket<C>> Connection<W, S> create()
    {
        return new Connection<W, S>();        
    }

    // Private constructor
    private Connection() {}
}

interface Color {}

interface Red extends Color {}
interface Green extends Color {}

interface Socket<C extends Color> {}
interface Wire<C extends Color> {}

class RedSocket implements Socket<Red> {}
class GreenSocket implements Socket<Green> {}
class RedWire implements Wire<Red> {}
class GreenWire implements Wire<Green> {}

public class CompatibleGenericsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection<RedWire, RedSocket> c0 = Connection.create(); // ok
        Connection<GreenWire, GreenSocket> c1 = Connection.create(); // ok
        Connection<GreenWire, RedSocket> c2 = Connection.create(); // error
    }
}
```

Comment: While the definition is a little more complicated, I'd vote for this approach given that consumption of the API becomes much more cleaner

Comment: I have done stuff like this before, I prefer this approach, but with the caveat that it makes the error (vs Tagir's solution) harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to mix-in an arbitrary properly like 'Color' is a typical trigger for the whole inheritance vs composition aka. is-a vs has-a debate. The general wisdom for a language like Java is that one should favor composition over inheritance in most general cases to avoid things like tricky wildcards. Other languages may offer more in the way of aspect-oriented programming

While other answers may help you achieve correct generics, I'd suggest reading over the [wikipedia page on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance%20%22) and thinking about whether you really need to enforce colour-matching at compile time or whether a runtime constructor check would do the job.