# Restrict generic upcasting

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have generic method with two parameters.

```java
<T> void compare(T a, T b) {}
```

Turns out, it is possible to pass parameters of any type: `T` may always be resolved to `Object`, because any other type *is a* `Object`.

Is there a way to make the method accepting parameters of *exactly* the same any type?

Comment: Are we talking about same compile time type or same runtime type here?

Comment: Consider the following: `Object a = new Object(), b = new Object(); inst.compare(a, b);`  Would this be ok?

Comment: If you need to check if they have the same runtime type: `a.getClass() == b.getClass()`.

Comment: Compile time – I want `compare("foo", 42)` to be compiling with an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the generic type of a generic Java method be used to enforce the type of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217236/can-the-generic-type-of-a-generic-java-method-be-used-to-enforce-the-type-of-arg)

Answer (score 2):

*Exactly* as in same class? No. If A and B share a parent class P, you will always be able to pass them both to a generic method expecting a `P`.

The only way I can see to restrict it would be to add a parameter like this:

```
<T> void compare(T a, T b, Class<T> clazz) {}
```

This will work because Java generics are invariant, meaning that if `A extends B`, `G<A>` and `G<B>` are completely disjoint types (one does not extend the other). For example, `List<Person>` and `List<Student>` are incompatible types even if `Student extends Person`. That's not intuitive and is simply a limitation of the language, some other languages like Scala have the option of making a generic type:

- invariant (so like Java)
- covariant (if `A extends B` then `G<A> extends G<B>`)
- contravariant (if `A extends B` then `G<B> extends G<A>`)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's dive down in your requirements:
You have a method

```
<T> void compare(T a, T b) {}
```

and you want to make sure it is only called with the same types.

Ok, let's use two Objects:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
compare(a, b);
```

Here I pass two Objects to your method. Of course anything is an object so, this small change would be also valid:

```
Object a = "Also an Object";
Object b = 42; // Boxing conversion
compare(a, b);
```

If you want to accept any type, you also have to accept `Object`s. And anything can be an object.

So, your requirement is impossible to satisfy at compile time.

---

But what about runtime?

That is actually doable and very easy:

```
<T> void compare(T a, T b) {
    if (a.getClass() != b.getClass()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("not the same type");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, good point. What I actually want here – is to restrict `"Also an Object"` and `42` upcasting to `Object`. That's probably against OOP concept...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there isn't a way to enforce that the parameters are of the same type accounting for all types *[(see other Stack Overflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30217236/2667225)*.

You can however, specify the type parameter when calling the method, although obviously this requires you to know the type to be used in a given situation e.g.

```
<Integer>compare(10, 22);
```

Comment: You should have flagged this question as duplicate. But good job finding it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't actually aware that I had the privilege yet to flag duplicate questions. I have done so now.